# Different result for a background image in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css

I have this site:

http://gazien.com/app.php/hello/javier

AS you can see the separator for the nav bar are shown different in Chrome and Firefox. I like the Firefox visialization. How can I get the same in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the border-image from `nav`. As this property is not effecting the style in firefox.

```
header nav {
clear: left;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
/*
border-image: url("/bundles/placasfrontend/images/linea.jpg");
-webkit-border-image: url("/bundles/placasfrontend/images/linea.jpg") 30 30 round;
-o-border-image: url("/bundles/placasfrontend/images/linea.jpg") 30 30 round;
border-image: url("/bundles/placasfrontend/images/linea.jpg") 30 30 round;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using prefixes in your CSS, which makes it render differently on Chrome and on Firefox. To make Chrome look like Firefox remove the border image on cf7228f.css, lines 90 and 92:

```
header nav {
  clear: left;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  /* border-image: url("/bundles/placasfrontend/images/linea.jpg"); */
  /* -webkit-border-image: url("/bundles/placasfrontend/images/linea.jpg") 30 30 round; */
  /* -o-border-image: url("/bundles/placasfrontend/images/linea.jpg") 30 30 round; */
  /* border-image: url("/bundles/placasfrontend/images/linea.jpg") 30 30 round; */
}
```